# How to fix "Incompatible Types" error in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, gradle, androidx

I am the beginner in Android studio and working on beginner project as a chat app. Working oc Fragment class there is a problem appeared :"Incompatible types"

I have tried other resolutions on the internet that i found but did not work.

Here is my class:

```
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;

public class TabsAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    public TabsAdapter(@NonNull FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {

        switch (position){

            case 0:
                RequestFragment requestfragment = new RequestFragment();
                return requestfragment;
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

and here is my Gradle:

```
compileSdkVersion 29
buildToolsVersion '29.0.1'
minSdkVersion 21
targetSdkVersion 29

            implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0-rc01'
            implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.0-beta2'
            implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha07'
            testİmplementation 'junit:junit:4.13-beta-3'
            androidTestİmplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.3.0-alpha01'
            androidTestİmplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0-alpha01'
            implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
            implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v13:1.0.0'
```

There is an error apperaing on `return requestfragment;` How can i fix it?

Comment: Please add your requestfragment.

Comment: `RequestFragment` extends `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` and not the androidx version.  You'll have to get an upgrade to RequestFragment or not use androidx for that class.  (I assumed RequestFragment is the whatsapp class)

Comment: Yeah, i am working on an app for learning like mobile chat app. When i import  android.support.v4.app.Fragment, cannot resolve symbol Fragment error appearing. I am using AndroidX for now but how can i use this kind of fragment? What should i do?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look in the `import` in your `requestfragment`.

Replace

```
import android.app.fragment
```

with

```
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
```

or

```
android.support.v4.app.Fragment
```

Comment: Hi, it didn't work. When i import  android.support.v4.app.Fragment, cannot resolve symbol Fragment error appearing.

Comment: @sercano07 Did you try _import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment_

Comment: it didn't work either. What should i do i don't know i'm just stucking.

Comment: @sercano07 Please add your requestfragment to your question

Comment: I am sorry but i didn't understand clearly, to where can i add to requestfragment exactly?

Comment: @sercano07 Click edit in this question and add the code.

Comment: its already added in the bottom of the question.  "There is an error apperaing on return requestfragment; How can i fix it?"

Comment: @sercano07 I mean top share the whole class. You have a class named RequestFragment and the code in this class is the Code you have to add.

Comment: This is the whole class already, i am just in the beginning. But facing that kind of error cannot continue.

Comment: You mean _RequestFragment()_ doesn't exist? The only case you use this code is in your FragmentPage class?